# HTML Email - Outlook.com won't recognise my vertical align control for an image

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook.com

I have an image in cell 1 of a 2 cell row.  There is text in cell 2.  Because Outlook.com decides to give extra spacing between text (compared to other browsers) it is distorting (adding height to) the whole row: but the image in cell 1 stays aligned to the top of the cell.

I have tried forcing the line height for the text, but that does not work.

Currently my code is:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" valign="middle">
<p style="text-align: center;">
<img style="margin: 0 auto; vertical-align: middle;" valign="middle" title="Date and Venue" alt="Date and Venue" src="imgURL" height="x" width="y">
</p>
</td>
```

But all these instructions are ignored by Outlook.com.

How do I make the image center itself in the cell?

Answer (score 3):

Images should always have `display:block;` in email. You don't need any of the margin or css align stuff. Here is a basic example for you:

```
<table width="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="100" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#cccccc">

<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="" width="50" height="50" alt="">

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```